# Read video with ffmpeg using moviepy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I have a video with variable frame rate, as I found out, moviepy does not support this.
I know that ffmpeg has this functionality: `ffmpeg-i <input> - filter:v fps=30 <output>`, but this is an inefficient method because I have to render the same video twice (the first is to stabilize it, and the second is when I use moviepy).
Is there a way to combine them in one operation ? (I mean instant reading video with constant frame rate)

Answer (score 0):

The `ffmpeg` command is just a thin wrapper around the `ffmpeg` libraries.  Anything you can script can, of course, be done with the library.  You might look at
https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python to see if it can solve your problem.